# how to build a reverse geocoding service

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

We want to build a web service like [google reverse geocoding](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/geocoding-reverse).

Of course, we will only provide the service for only a specified region.

Then we want to know things we need to implement it.

By now, we have the pois,roads data of the region with ESRI Shapefile data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESRI shapefile data, it probably already has address ranges for each road segment in the forms of four variables (e.g. LFROMHN --> LTOHN & RFROMHN --> RTOHN).

If not, you can satisfy this information with Census road [edges](ftp://ftp.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/EDGES/).